# Nginx location not work on digital-ocean

Tags: node.js, nginx, location, digital-ocean

I created two node.js instance on DigitalOcean's Ubuntu machine.
Both listen to localhost, with different ports.
Then test by curl http:\localhost:${port}.  Both worked.

Then I added them to  /etc/nginx/site-available/default

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8837;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

location /app {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9837;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Only  http://${ip_address}:${port}/  worked.

http://${ip_address}:${port}/app  return 
"Cannot GET /app"

I used express in node.js  is it the problem come from?

Comment: Can you post your nginx error logs? They're commonly found in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

Comment: Thanks Oliver,  I can not find error.log since I move app to another port by copy default which in /etc/nginx/sites-available/,  and listen another port.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where is wrong, here is what I found:

If remove express  from node.js  and listen port like this:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  ...
}).listen(8001, 'localhost');
```

The /app worked,  no error happen.
If use express like this:

```
const app = express();
app.listen(8001, 'localhost', function() {
   ...
});
```

/app will return error.

To resolve this problem I open another port that create another configuration by copy /etc/nginx/sites-available/default ,then link it to /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default2 /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
and change the port in server{}